# Spark caching jdbc load

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Am trying to  use spark to load millions of records (96,509,080) from a table, parallelizing it to load faster (`numPartition = 10,000`) so I can query super fast from the in memory data (under `ms`).

But I noticed the performance wasn't terribly fast as I expected so I thought of re-partitioning before `cache-ing` to reduce the partitions of my cached dataframe.

Now, it seems after the initial data load it cached 10,0000 (`numPartition = 10,000`) and the spark job shows no activities (stages or tasks) after and there are no failures which makes me clueless to what's going on.

I like to know from experienced Spark users, if the inactivity occurs because spark is re-partitioning the cache to 100 and is there any thing to check to see the progress?

```
val opts = Map(
                    "url"     -> s"jdbc:postgresql://$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT/$DATABASE",
                    "driver"  -> "org.postgresql.Driver",
                    "dbtable" -> DB_TABLE,
                    "user"    -> DB_USER,
                    "password"-> DB_PASSWORD,
                    "partitionColumn" -> "id",
                    "lowerBound" -> "1",
                    "upperBound" -> "96509080",      
                    "numPartitions" -> "10000"       
                )

  val reportsDf = sparkSession.read.format("jdbc").options(opts).load

  reportsDf.createOrReplaceTempView("custom_reports")

  val reportId = reportsDf.select("fileId").distinct.as[String].collect()

  reportId.repartition(100).cache()

 ....
```

Some specs here,

Am running the latest Spark 2.0,

2 machine 8 cores and 60G memory each.

Thanks

Comment: a) repartitioning is lazy, b) repartitioning creates new data frame (on a side note Spark is not a database and expecting ms latency when task scheduling is typically in tens of ms is unrealistic).

Comment: @zero323 - thanks for giving me more insights about Spark